# Detect current with USB and Java

Tags: java, usb

To check if a 'switch' is open or closed and detecting that in Java, I have the following plan: I won't use the data pins, just the USB 5V current, and if the switch is closed there is a current, which I should detect in Java, and so it will be processed by my program.
Would there be a simple solution for this or do I need to find and try out a whole Java usb library for it, of which I would use just a tiny little bit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just curious, but what is the application?  It sounds like a clever way to do it, but there may be something easier.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work in the way you describe it. Have you ever connected a gadget like  USB lamp or USB fan? Then you would know that the Software/OS does not even *know* about them.

The USB spec says you can draw up to 100mA from a port without telling anyone about it, and 500mA when declared in the USB protocol. Most USB HDDs draw quite some more than the allowed 500mA maximum USB2 current.

To make your application work, you absolutely need a device which can talk over USB. This *could* be an USB=>RS232 adapter (which your application can talk to using RXTX) or a HID device like a USB Joystick. Joysticks can have buttons and switches.

Answer (score 0):

You could try RXTX. This is a library written for serial communication with Java. http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/. You will have to use native libraries, and I don't know if it would be able to detect if there is a current or not on the USB.

Comment: It is **not** possible with RXTX to detect *current* on USB.

Comment: *"I don't know if it would be able to detect if there is a current or not on the USB.*" Then what's the point of this answer?